# Parsing PDF file using Regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pdf

I am trying to parse some object elements from a PDF file using re module of Python. My goal is to parse each PDF object using a regular expression.
A PDF object example is the following:

```
1 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Pages
    /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
    /Count 1
>>
endobj
...
```

When I use `"\d+\s\d+\sobj[\s,\S]*endobj"` it doesn't work (it keeps parsing util last endobj is found). How can I modify regular expression in order to parse each object seperately (in other words the part from 1 0 obj until endobj)?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using only regex, it is easy to construct a PDF file that your program will not be able to handle. PDF dictionaries and lists can contain other objects. Regex can't handle recursive structures, at least not Python re module.

A pdf file is a tree of objects and streams:

- Dictionaries: `<<` (name value)* `>>`
- Lists: `[` (value)* `]`
- Names: `/` (regular char)*
- Strings: `(` (char)* `)`
- Hex strings: `<` (hexchar)* `>`
- Numbers: (`-`)? ((digit)+ | (digit)+ `.` (digit)* | `.` (digit)+)
- Booleans: `true` | `false`
- References: (digit)+ (whitespace)+ (digit)+ (whitespace)+ `R`

Whitespace and comments are ignored in most places.
Comments start with `%` and run until the end of the line.

Indirect objects are specified as:

```
1 0 obj
(any object)
endobj
```

This object can then be referenced as `1 0 R`. Indirect dictionaries can also have a stream attached:

```
1 0 obj
<<
/Length 22
>>
stream
(22 bytes of raw data)
endstream
endobj
```

A PDF file looks something like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
%ÿÿÿÿ
1 0 obj
<< /Author (MizardX) >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
% more required keys
>>
endobj
%lots of more indirect objects, one after another
trailer
<<
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 2 0 R
% ... more required keys
>>
xref
0 3
0000000000 65535 f
0000000015 00000 n
0000000054 00000 n
startxref
225
%%EOF
```

The root of the object tree is the `trailer` object. Every objects is referenced directly or indirectly from this dictionary.

There are a lot more complexity hidden inside the streams, but that does not affect the file structure.

The full specification can be found at [Adobe's website](http://www.adobe.ca/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `*?`as the non-greedy version - see [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Also, note that PDF format is very complex - especially when it starts having binary streams within it - but if you know the PDFs you are looking at are simple then this should work.

Answer (score 2):

A question mark after the repeated part should take the minimal amount of characters. Also comma is not necessary because `\S` already takes it into account.

```
\d+\s\d+\sobj[\s\S]*?endobj
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your exact question, but you might want to have look at existing pdf parsing libraries in python, for example: [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) or [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/). (even if you do not end up using them, you might as well have a look and see how they do it)